# Yii2: Conditional Validator always returns required

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I am trying to use Yii2's conditional validator as given in the guide like:

Model code

```
public function rules()
{
   // $discharged = function($model) { return $this->discharged == 1; };
    return [
        [[ 'admission_date','discharge_date', 'doctor_appointment_date', 'operation_date'], 'safe'],
        [[ 'package','tpa_name', 'discharged', 'bed_type', 'room_category', 'ref_doctor', 'consultant_doctor', 'operation_name'], 'integer'],
        [['advance_amount', 'operation_charges'], 'number'],
        [['patient_name', 'ref_doctor_other'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['general_regn_no', 'ipd_patient_id'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['admission_date', 'discharge_date', 'doctor_appointment_date', 'operation_date'],'default','value'=>null],
        ['ipd_patient_id', 'unique'],

        [['bed_type','admission_date','room_category'],'required'],

        ['discharge_date', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
            return $model->discharged == 1;
        }],


    ];
}
```

and in my Controller like:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new PatientDetail();     

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

But whether I select or not the discharged field which is a checkbox field, the discharge date alwasys returns as required.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Add the rest validation rules, scenarios (if they are exist) and controller code.

Comment: Hi arogachev - there is no hint in the docs for controller code for this validation, can you elaborate how to do that?

Comment: I mean post what you have at this moment.

Comment: OK I have updated the question with the view code for these two fields. Do you need any other info.

Comment: Actually I asked about model and controller code (see first comment).

Comment: Sorry arogachev - updated the model and controller code.

Comment: @Pawan do you get any solution? i am facing same issue.

Answer (score 42):

It seems that by default Yii2 will do validation in **BOTH** Server side and Client side. Check the example in `Conditional Validation` part of [Yii2 doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation):

```
['state', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
    return $model->country == 'USA';
}, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
    return $('#country').val() == 'USA';
}"],
```

you also need a `'whenClient'` code, or as @Alexandr Bordun said, to disable the client validation by `'enableClientValidation' => false`.

Comment: Thanks for give the hint :)

Answer (score 16):

Try to add **enableClientValidation** parameter as the following:

```
 ['discharge_date', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
        return $model->discharged == 1;
 }, 'enableClientValidation' => false]
```

Answer (score 4):

This only worked for me when using the model name (client validation).

```js
['state', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
  return $model->country == 'USA';
}, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
  return $('#MODELNAMEHERE-country').val() == 'USA';
}"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
['package_id_fk', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {return $model->type == 'PACKAGE';}, 'enableClientValidation' => false],
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

i had the similar requirement i solved it using the following code

```
['discharge_date', 'required', 'whenClient' => function($model) {
        return $model->discharged == 1;
 }, 'enableClientValidation' => false]
```

Comment: same answer as @Alexandr Bordun but with a type: `'whenClient'` should be `'when'`. You can't use a PHP function on the client side ;)